# How to integrate jacoco plugin with gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I need to integrate jacoco plugin in to build.gradle or grade.properties file. anyone help me with setting this

Answer (score 1):

Please check documentation of JaCoCo Gradle Plugin - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

For example you can add

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
// ...

test {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacoco.exec");
    }
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file.